# MySQL specific number of entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Hello i have got a Mysql table that i fill within a php script. In this script i check if the number of entries of a specific type has reached the maximum to inform the customer. If the number of entries is less i let him insert a new entry into my table. The table looks like this

```
--------------------
Date          | Type 
--------------------
Tuesday 13:00 | Car
```

And the php script that checks looks like this

```
<?php

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM Table WHERE Date='Tuesday 13:00' AND Type='Car'"); 
$sql ->execute(); 
$sql_rows = $sql->fetchColumn();

if ($sql_rows > 20){ 

echo "All entries for this type has been filled please choose another to continue"; 

}else{ 

$insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Table VALUES('Tuesday 13:00', 'Car')");
$insert -> execute(); 

} 
?>
```

My problem now is that if 100 people access this php script at the same moment will the php script allow exactly 19 people to insert themselves 'Tuesday 13:00','Car'  into the database or more and how could i prevent that without creating inconvenience to the clients?

Comment: Wouldn't 100 people potentially end up at the if statement and find $sql_rows to be 0, and all try and insert 100 rows together?  What you're doing doesn't look safe.

Comment: This has to be controlled on the database server end not just the PHP code. You need a key or unique constraint to the table that will prevent the insert.

Comment: That`s what i ask. Is there a better-safer way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a transaction to ensure that both queries work with the same snapshot of the table. The transaction will lock the table so that other people will wait. Put `$conn->startTransaction()` before the first `SELECT` query, add a `FOR UPDATE` clause to the query, and `$conn->commit()` after the `INSERT`.

You must be using InnoDB, not MyISAM, for transactions to be effective.

```
<?php

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM Table 
                        WHERE Date='Tuesday 13:00' AND Type='Car' 
                        FOR UPDATE"); 
$conn->startTransaction();
$sql ->execute(); 
$sql_rows = $sql->fetchColumn();

if ($sql_rows > 20){ 
    echo "All entries for this type has been filled please choose another to continue"; 
}else{ 
    $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Table VALUES('Tuesday 13:00', 'Car')");
    $insert -> execute(); 
} 
$conn->commit();
```

Comment: Do i need to lock the table during inserting when i use this way?

Comment: You can use the `FOR UPDATE` option in the `SELECT` query to make it lock the table.